# How to place 2 NSTextView vertically aligned with a space in between, and make container view resize accordingly with auto layout

Tags: xcode, cocoa, autolayout

Hope the title is clear. Trying to have something below

```
 --------------------
 | [titleTextView]  |
 |        |         |
 | [detailsTextView]|
 --------------------
```

With the code that I tried, the container resized, but both titletextView and detailsTextView are placed together (overlapping each others). I know I init both at (16,0) but shouldn't the constrain place them correctly?

I also get the following error: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
("<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000008fcd0 NSTextView:0x600000134be0.bottom == NSView:0x600000134c80.bottom + 20>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000093ce0 h=--& v=--& V:[NSTextView:0x600000134be0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x600000134c80 )>")`

Code:

```
//title textView
self.titleTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(16, 0, [self.view frame].size.width - 30, 0)];
[self.titleTextView setEditable:NO];
[self.titleTextView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[self.titleTextView setString:@"potentially long text."];
[self.titleTextView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];
[self.titleTextView sizeToFit];

//detail textView
self.detailsTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(16, 0, [self.view frame].size.width - 30, 0)];
[self.detailsTextView setEditable:NO];
[self.detailsTextView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[self.detailsTextView setString:@"Very long text."];
[self.detailsTextView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];
[self.detailsTextView sizeToFit];

//Adding to self.view
[self.view addSubview: self.titleTextView];
[self.view addSubview: self.detailsTextView];

[self.view addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.titleTextView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.detailsTextView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:20]];
[self.view addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.titleTextView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.view
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:20]];

[self.view addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.detailsTextView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.view
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:20]];
```

Comment: Should I do this with IB, this will take 10seconds???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with autolayout, you don't want to think about the layout in terms of frames at all.  The constraints will determine the frame of your views.

Also, if you're creating the layout in code, you have to call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` for the views which you want the autolayout engine to apply to.

So, you'd want to do something like:

```
UIView* titleTextView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[titleTextView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
UIView* detailsTextView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[detailsTextView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

...additional setup stuff...

[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[titleTextView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleTextView)]];
[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[detailsTextView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(detailsTextView)]];
[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[titleTextView][detailsTextView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleTextView, detailsTextView)]];
```

If working in code, I'd strongly recommend checking out the [visual format language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) which will make setting up constraints much more efficient in code, but you can also do the same thing as above using individual constraints.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code, but now nothing shows up. The container view has a frame size of zero.

Comment: If you are just starting getting use to autolayout make a few simple projects and use IB to apply the constraints. This is a good way to learn and get a feel for what you later might want to do in code. The view is probably not showing up because the UI elements in your view don't have an intrinsic content size or any explicit size constraints. Again, this you can catch this sort of thing easily in IB.

Answer (score 1):

Forget all you've done earlier with rects and start thinking in relative positions.

Using my favorite category for autolayout:
https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

you can achieve what you want with these simple constraints (which I find MUCH more readable and intuitive than any of the official API solutions):

```
[self.titleTextView pinToSuperviewEdges:JRTViewPinLeftEdge|JRTViewPinTopEdge inset:20.0];
[self.detailsTextView pinToSuperviewEdges:JRTViewPinLeftEdge inset:20.0];
[self.detailsTextView pinEdge:NSLayoutAttributeTop toEdge:NSLayoutAttributeBottom ofView:self.titleTextView inset:20];
```

This will pin both textviews 20 pixels from the left, titleTextView 20 pixels from the top and detailsTextView 20 pixels below titleTextView. Also, the category will add the constraints to the correct view in each case.